# Unable to launch Cloudant DB from Bluemix console

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am facing an issue with Cloudant DB, in my Bluemix project where none of the apps present in the Bluemix project dashboard are able to launch the Database service. When I attempt to launch this DB from the Bluemix console using the Launch option provided when Cloudant is added as a service,I get an error saying that the server is taking too long to respond or the site may be unavailable.

The details for the DB are provided below :
host": "8eb92b78-aca3-4bdf-bd96-a0482df2b60c-bluemix.cloudant.com"
"port": 443
"url": "https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__8eb92b78-2Daca3-2D4bdf-2Dbd96-2Da0482df2b60c-2Dbluemix-3Ad5ae2c3b403d47cf279a56248575ea559b90f0b062c71125959cbccf0bb264a1-408eb92b78-2Daca3-2D4bdf-2Dbd96-2Da0482df2b60c-2Dbluemix.cloudant.com&d=DwIF-g&c=jf_iaSHvJObTbx-siA1ZOg&r=mPCb2qXM-FSowwk9620CFoaF37QJBGk5AS6la4L55Oo&m=HFcvyyH6rBZPwPglis8IDUQ1K2ieHIvtJt1Kd0IXZE0&s=ZtCJb634CeCu22OnW9e9X0Wmh8SCfgyOP-6T8lloxOI&e="
"plan": "Shared Dedicated",

Any guidance regarding why I may be facing this issue and how to get it resolved will be much appreciated!

Note : I was able to launch the DB from Bluemix as expected, earlier. So, I am not sure what has caused it to stop working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with the back end service.  Please raise a support ticket for more help.

Comment: Thank you for the response! It was a VPN issue. It was finally resolved after modifying the etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said, this sounds like a back end service issue and a support ticket might be your fastest solution. You can submit a support ticket here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/support/index.html#getting-help